# Concatenation using a do while loop

Tags: java, string, do-while, string-concatenation, sentinel

I'm trying to read user input and then concatenate those words with a space between them. I'm having trouble figuring out the logic within the loop. I also want the user to be able to tell my program when they are finished entering words. Here is what I have so far...it's not much.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  String userWords = "";
  int number = 0;

  System.out.println("Enter words to build a sentence");
  userWords = in.nextLine();

  int i = 1;
  do {
      System.out.println(userWords);
      i++;
  } while (!(userWords.equals(null))); {
      System.out.println(userWords + " ");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  String userWords = "";
  String currentWord = "";
  // now we print a prompt for user
  System.out.println("Enter words to build a sentence");  
  // here is the reading loop
  do {
      // now we read next line from user
      currentWord = in.nextLine();
      // now we add the user input to the userWords with " "
      userWords += currentWord +" ";
      // we end the loop when the currentWord will be empty
  } while (!(currentWord.trim().isEmpty())); 
  // now we print all the words
  System.out.println(userWords);
```

Comment: when i enter the while portion of the loop it gives a error and says "left hand side must be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Try it now, I've fixed this

Comment: I don't think so. "Enter words to build a sentence" will be written after every new input line.And there will be two spaces behind the last word.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  String enteredWord = "";
  StringBuilder builder = new sb();
  System.out.println("Enter words to build a sentence");
  enteredWord = in.nextLine();
  do {

      sb.append(enteredWord);
      sb.append(" ");
      enteredWord = in.nextLine();

  } while (!(enteredWord.equals("exit"))); 
//you may want to use a special case like %% instead because exit can be in a sentence{
          System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

that should work for the most part I dont have anywhere to test it right now. Each time round the loop adds the word with a space following it and asks for a new word. you can use `userwords += in.nextline() + " ";` either but in a loop I would alsways use stringbuilder for efficiency.